# How does ajax work on SO with javascript coming from different domains?

Tags: discussion, ajax

This might be stupid question, but how does ajax work on SO given that the javascript files are being served by a different domain?  I thought AJAX did not allow cross-domain requests.

Comment: Belongs on stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @Pesto: Probably does, yeah, but you can see why he asked it in meta. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is based on the location of the document loading the script, not the script's location.  That's why CDNs like Google's Ajax API hosting (code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/) and the AOL CDN work for distributing JavaScript libraries.

Comment: Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Are you asking if JS can Request Cross-domain? If so...

It has methods of working, such as JSONP and [PMXDR](http://eligrey.com/projects/pmxdr). But I'm fairly sure the receiving URL has to explicitly allow JSONP requests. That, or you can create your own proxy script with a technology that can stand between local javascript, and remote content.

That being said, not sure specifically how SO is doing it.

#### Are you asking if JS can be loaded cross-domain? If so...

Yes. Similar to images, mp3's, style-sheets, etc., Anything public really. If it's out there in the open, then you can load it. Google hosts many js-libraries in this fashion - you just load them from the central server, meaning your visitors may already have them cached.

Comment: All AJAX requests are still made on the site's origin. You can include JS files from any source you want.

Comment: @Ian, I think you missunderstood me. I know you can include js from any source, but that doesn't mean you can contact any source *with* js.

Comment: I believe the original question was referencing *loading* from external domains, but your answer now includes that so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Ian, The question is confusing, but the following lead me to provide my first answer "...I thought AJAX did not allow cross-domain requests."